# Read/write instance variables within/outside an infinite run loop, in class extending multiprocessing.Process Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, instance-variables, python-multiprocessing

## Instance variables in python multiprocessing

I have a multiprocess program that handles burst of I/O data on one serial port, from multiple independent sensors.
After a timeout period of no data from the port, I want to run a callback function.

I previously used threading (with the same structure as below), but the locking interrupts the data flow too much, so that is why I'm trying to switch to multiprocess.

With multiprocessing the I/O works really well, but I then run into the problem:

It seems **instance** variables are not shared inside and outside the infinite run loop in a class that extends Process and I'm having a hard time finding documentation of, exactly how you are supposed to use instance variables with pythons multiprocessing.

The problem in the code below is that self.triggered *in* the run-loop and *outside* the run loop are different instances, so the callback function is never invoked.

*What would be the proper way to read/write instance variables from within/outside an infinite run loop in a class that extends multiprocessing.Process in Python 2.7?*

## Enviroment

Python 2.7.11 x64 OSX 10.10.5

## Code

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time
class ProcessTimer(Process):
    def __init__(self, callback, timeout):
        Process.__init__(self)
        self.callback = callback
        self.timeout = timeout
        self.trigger = False
        self.time = time.time()
        self.nap = self.timeout / 4
        self.triggerTime = time.time()
        
    def run(self):
        self.triggerTime = time.time()

        while 1:
            # check how much time has passed
            # test callback
            # self.callback() # this works
            elapsedTime = time.time() - self.triggerTime
            print "ProcessTimer: run() - elapsedTime:" + str(elapsedTime) + " trigger is: " + str(self.trigger) + " triggerTime is: " + str(self.triggerTime)
            if (elapsedTime > self.timeout):
                if (self.trigger):
                    print "ProcessTimer: run() - trigger callback is true - this never happens(?)" + str(self.timeout) 
                    self.trigger = False
                    self.callback()
            
            time.sleep(self.nap)

    def restartTimer(self):
        print "ProcessTimer: restartTimer() - trigger was: " + str(self.trigger) + " triggerTime was: " + str(self.triggerTime)
        self.triggerTime = time.time()
        self.trigger = True
        print "ProcessTimer: restartTimer() - now trigger is set to: " + str(self.trigger) + " triggerTime is: " + str(self.triggerTime)
              
def testfunc():
    print "func called"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    t = ProcessTimer(testfunc, 10)
    t.start()
    time.sleep(5)
    t.restartTimer()
```

## Output

We can see here in the output from the program that self.trigger is False and then updated to True, but this happens outside the run-loop only, the variable is not shared it seems. triggerTime is updated too, but only outside the loop.

ProcessTimer: **run()** - elapsedTime:1.00135803223e-05 trigger is: **False** triggerTime is: **1452437777.24**

ProcessTimer: run() - elapsedTime:2.00103807449 trigger is: False triggerTime is: 1452437777.24

ProcessTimer: run() - elapsedTime:4.00216698647 trigger is: False triggerTime is: 1452437777.24

ProcessTimer: **restartTimer()** - trigger was: **False** triggerTime was: **1452437777.23**

ProcessTimer: **restartTimer()** - now trigger is set to: ***True*** triggerTime is: ***1452437782.24***

ProcessTimer: run() - elapsedTime:6.00229310989 trigger is: ***False*** triggerTime is: ***1452437777.24***

ProcessTimer: run() - elapsedTime:8.00314497948 trigger is: False triggerTime is: 1452437777.24